# Recent breakage of google-sign-in with flutter on Chrome?

Tags: firebase, google-chrome, flutter, google-signin

As of 1 day ago, I seem to have trouble with google sign in running inside a flutter app on firebase.

When loading the webapp, I see an exception with obfuscated stack traces:

```
Uncaught TypeError: t.gpT is not a function
    at Im.$1 (google_sign_in_web.dart:113)
    at Object.a4P (js_helper.dart:1060)
    at Object.Yq (core_patch.dart:84)
    at a6F (js_patch.dart:541)
    at js_patch.dart:519
    at e.zo (cb=gapi.loaded_0:200)
    at lk (cb=gapi.loaded_0:203)
    at gk (cb=gapi.loaded_0:203)
    at _.Rj.hU (cb=gapi.loaded_0:203)
    at Qj (cb=gapi.loaded_0:195)
```

This happens when deploying on firebase and on Chrome, not when running on localhost (same chrome), or when using the firebase deployment on Safari.

I'm properly stumped - I don't remember having upgraded the browser or changing anything in the code. Neither do I remember having fiddled with the oauth tokens.

Any ideas how to properly debug this ? I'm fairly inexperienced in dart/firebase/JS.

[Update]: I found that I can reproduce this even with the Google provided example at:

```
https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/google_sign_in/google_sign_in/example
```

This works when I run it with `flutter run -d chrome` or  `flutter run -s web-server`

When I do a `firebase deploy`, the app runs fine in Safari. In Chrome I get above exception. I tried to disable all extensions, same thing.

Comment: Exact same issue. Deployed on Firebase, works perfectly on Safari. Doesn't even show a pop-up on Chrome. Allowed all cookies, still the same.

Answer (score 1):

Aha! The culprit here was blocking of third party cookies. If I turn off third party cookie blocking, things work fine.

Yikes, this makes using Google-sign-in unusable for webapps whose customers are blocking third party cookies.

Comment: And this is also true when trying to use the firebase equivalent described in ```https://github.com/funwithflutter/tutorials/tree/master/001-Flutter-Web-Firebase-Auth-Google``` - third party cookies must be allowed :(

Comment: I have allowed all cookies in my Chrome. Still the same issue. Works fine on Safari

Comment: Are you sure you're having no chrome extensions set ? There may also be problems with same-site cookies (overridden via Chrome flags). The sign-in library seems fairly troubled, I just switched to usernames and passwords, for which firebase has support.

Does your console give any useful errors other than this one?